# Why is the Neo4j java process opening ports in large blocks in random ranges?

Tags: java, tcp, neo4j, port

It appears that Neo4j 3.4.1 (Windows) is using more ports than what they state in their documentation (see https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/ports/).  In addition to the standard ports for connections it is also opening large blocks of ports.  We've seen from about 20 to 250 ports being opened in relatively contiguous blocks anywhere in the 5000s to 35000s. These are all ports opened by the same Java process (Neo4j server run as a console application) or the Commons Daemon Server Runner process (Windows service).  The ports appeared to be paired off where every two ports are established in a TCP connection with each other.

I cannot figure out what these ports or for or any documentation that mentions the use of these ports.  It seems that the number of ports is relative to the size of the database.

I've also looked at Neo4j 2.3.2 and it seems to be using some mystery ports as well, though the block size was only six in that case.

Since we are using the APOC libraries, I removed it from the plugins directory and performed a restart of the server to see if that had any impact.  That does not seem to be an issue.

It certainly would be nice to understand why the process is using these ports; however, the fundamental problem is that it is acting like a bad citizen, hogging large blocks of ports where better behaved applications tend to exist. Is there a way to control in what range they will be opened? It seems that if these port blocks are necessary, then they should be opened in the Ephemeral port range and not trounce upon other applications.

Edit: Per suggestion by @InverseFalcon, here is an example of occupied ports by the Java process using Neo4j 3.5.3:

```
    H:\>netstat -a -o | find /I "17048"
      TCP    0.0.0.0:7473           mysvr:0              LISTENING       17048
      TCP    0.0.0.0:7474           mysvr:0              LISTENING       17048
      TCP    0.0.0.0:7687           mysvr:0              LISTENING       17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36418        mysvr:36419          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36419        mysvr:36418          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36420        mysvr:36421          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36421        mysvr:36420          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36422        mysvr:36423          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36423        mysvr:36422          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36424        mysvr:36425          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36425        mysvr:36424          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36426        mysvr:36427          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36427        mysvr:36426          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36428        mysvr:36429          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36429        mysvr:36428          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36430        mysvr:36431          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36431        mysvr:36430          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36432        mysvr:36433          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36433        mysvr:36432          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36434        mysvr:36435          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36435        mysvr:36434          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36436        mysvr:36437          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36437        mysvr:36436          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36438        mysvr:36439          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36439        mysvr:36438          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36440        mysvr:36441          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36441        mysvr:36440          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36442        mysvr:36443          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36443        mysvr:36442          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36444        mysvr:36445          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36445        mysvr:36444          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36446        mysvr:36447          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36447        mysvr:36446          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36448        mysvr:36449          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36449        mysvr:36448          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36450        mysvr:36451          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36451        mysvr:36450          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36452        mysvr:36453          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36453        mysvr:36452          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36454        mysvr:36455          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36455        mysvr:36454          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36456        mysvr:36457          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36457        mysvr:36456          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36458        mysvr:36459          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36459        mysvr:36458          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36460        mysvr:36461          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36461        mysvr:36460          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36462        mysvr:36463          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36463        mysvr:36462          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36464        mysvr:36465          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36465        mysvr:36464          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36466        mysvr:36467          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36467        mysvr:36466          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36468        mysvr:36469          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36469        mysvr:36468          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36470        mysvr:36471          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36471        mysvr:36470          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36472        mysvr:36473          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36473        mysvr:36472          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36474        mysvr:36475          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36475        mysvr:36474          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36476        mysvr:36477          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36477        mysvr:36476          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36478        mysvr:36479          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36479        mysvr:36478          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    [::]:7473              mysvr:0              LISTENING       17048
      TCP    [::]:7474              mysvr:0              LISTENING       17048
      TCP    [::]:7687              mysvr:0              LISTENING       17048
      TCP    [::1]:7687             mysvr:36483          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    [::1]:7687             mysvr:36484          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    [::1]:7687             mysvr:36485          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    [::1]:7687             mysvr:36486          ESTABLISHED     17048
      TCP    [::1]:7687             mysvr:36487          ESTABLISHED     17048
```

If bolt is turned off, the block is smaller:

```
H:\>netstat -a -o | find /I "20520"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7473           mysvr:0              LISTENING       20520
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7474           mysvr:0              LISTENING       20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36902        mysvr:36903          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36903        mysvr:36902          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36904        mysvr:36905          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36905        mysvr:36904          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36906        mysvr:36907          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36907        mysvr:36906          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36908        mysvr:36909          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36909        mysvr:36908          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36910        mysvr:36911          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36911        mysvr:36910          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36912        mysvr:36913          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    127.0.0.1:36913        mysvr:36912          ESTABLISHED     20520
  TCP    [::]:7473              mysvr:0              LISTENING       20520
  TCP    [::]:7474              mysvr:0              LISTENING       20520
```

And if https is turned off, it is even smaller:

```
    H:\>netstat -a -o | find /I "20556"
      TCP    0.0.0.0:7474           mysvr:0              LISTENING       20556
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36962        mysvr:36963          ESTABLISHED     20556
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36963        mysvr:36962          ESTABLISHED     20556
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36964        mysvr:36965          ESTABLISHED     20556
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36965        mysvr:36964          ESTABLISHED     20556
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36966        mysvr:36967          ESTABLISHED     20556
      TCP    127.0.0.1:36967        mysvr:36966          ESTABLISHED     20556
      TCP    [::]:7474              mysvr:0              LISTENING       20556
```

Comment: I'll see what we know about this, but can you also test with newer versions? 3.4.12 is the newest along the 3.4.x line, and 3.5.3 is our latest along 3.5.x.

Comment: Also is this with Neo4j Desktop, or from a server zip/tar install?

Comment: I tried a new download of neo4j 3.4.12 and 3.5.3.  They both do the same thing (opening blocks of ports aside from what is documented).

We use the Windows zip install.

Comment: Whatever is going on here, I don't think this is Neo4j. The ports `7473`, `7474`, and `7687` that are listening are the expected ports that Neo should open. We don't recognize any of the others. What you have shows connections are established yet nothing is listening. Something else is doing this, either some other program, or some virus or anti-virus operation.

Comment: Scratch that, we may have been able to reproduce something similar. We'll get engineering to investigate what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this may be a consequence that socketpairs are not supported on Windows, so pipes are implemented as loopback connections. While this originated with Windows XP it looks like it has continued for Windows systems. It looks as if the port numbers used have likewise been changed or at least left unrestricted.

This is captured at the end of this [older Java bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6907260):

> Windows doesn't support socketpairs so Pipe is implemented as a loopback connection on that platform. The "client" side of that connection doesn't explicitly bind and so it allocated an ephemeral port in the range 1024-5000.

java.io.OutputStream usages would be implemented as a loopback in this way.

I'll do some followup to see if we can get any more info.

Comment: Given this as the case, I'd suggest that the Neo4j documentation should be updated to note that these ports are opened on Windows deployments.  From the link @InverseFalcon provided that described the issue, we were able to diagnose that the dynamic port range on the server we are using was wide open and changed it to the default ephemeral port range for Windows using the command: netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=49152 num=16384